# Is there a way to programmatically alter a field's schema?

Tags: 7, media, entities, database

Is there a way to modify a fields schema programmatically? I'd like the image field to have a "Premium" checkbox, but I need to store this data somewhere. Also, it needs to work for current fields and future fields as they are created.

Comment: You could use Field Columns: https://drupal.org/sandbox/rudiedirkx/2146351 but it requires a core patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the API function [hook_schema_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7).

Though you should also be aware that the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module exists specifically to solve this particular problem in a much nicer way.